# how to use sqlalchemy: filter_by - filter_by not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Please review my below code. I am trying to return a JSON object, from my sql query through the api endpoint, However step by step simple instructions doesn't seem to simple. My query doesn't work.  Here is my code below:

```
import pyodbc
import jsonify
from flask import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Secret Key"
 

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc://@DESKTOP-U1RFE6J/crud?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

  
#Creating model table for our CRUD database
class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
 
 
    def __init__(self, name, email, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

class dataSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        load_instance = True
datas_schema = dataSchema(many=True)
data_schema = dataSchema()
data_schemaname = dataSchema()

 
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def Index():
    all_data = Data.query.all()
    data_schema = dataSchema()
    result = datas_schema.dump(all_data)
    return jsonify(result)


#getting particular post
#eg: http://127.0.0.1:5000/filter_id/10/
@app.route('/filter_id/<id>/', methods = ['GET'])
def filter_id(id):
    queryresultid = Data.query.get(id).all()
    return data_schema.jsonify(queryresultid)


#filter by name 
@app.route('/filter_name/<namea>/', methods = ['GET'])
def filter_name(namea):
    queryresultname = Data.query.filter_by(name = namea).all()
    return jsonify(queryresultname)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Once I run the above, I get the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
[SQL: SELECT data.id AS data_id, data.name AS data_name, data.email AS data_email, data.phone AS data_phone
FROM data
WHERE data.name = ?]
[parameters: ('Rebekah',)]

What I have tried is a lot of Googling, which doesn't work, I have tried as well to use a static string as a "filter" criteria, which gives me the same error.  As I see in the error, that the variable from my API url does pull through, but it refuses to filter by the variable.

Comment: I'd guess `Data.name` is of type `nvarchar` in the db, so the SQLAlchemy type should be too - see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.NVARCHAR).  Quite how you would do this using flask-sqlalchemy I'm not sure.

Comment: Data.name is text in my db.  I have changed it to nvchar(max) now, which gives me a different problem, Now when I run my program, it returns a set of empty curly brackets.

Comment: If it's text, then use the [Text type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.TEXT); the point is, you want the db type and the SQLA type to match up.